# Why I get only heartbeats?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coinbase-api, gdax-api

I have the code at the bottom to subscribe. Something I must do wrong because I get the only heartbeat messages. How can I get the messages if there was a match?
I tried it with the new endpoint with the same result.
Should this api work with EUR as well? because it works with USD like ETH-USD but don't see it with eur.
Thank you

```
const socket = new gdax_1.WebsocketClient(
    ['ETH-EUR'],
    'wss://ws-feed-public.sandbox.gdax.com',
    undefined,
    { channels: ['matches'] },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. It was because I connected to the sandbox, and the match data from the sandbox is different than live. It seems there is no mock service for ETH-EUR.